# Are there any open problems in mathematics whose resolutions would have important physical implications?

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, mathematics

Are there any open problems in pure mathematics whose resolutions would resolve a well-formulated open physics question, whose solution could (at least in principle) explain an experimentally measurable phenomenon?

For example, I've heard that a proof of the Riemann hypothesis could settle some important open physics problems, but I don't know the details.

This question is broad, so let me try to clarify what I'm looking for. By an "open question in math" I mean a question that is considered to have purely mathematical interest apart from any possible physical applications, and so is under active research by pure mathematicians rather than physicists. (For example, the question of whether the Hubbard model on the square lattice has a d-wave superconducting phase is certain a purely mathematical question which would have lots of important physics implications, but I don't think any mathematicians are working on it, as it's not terribly interesting from a pure math standpoint.)

Two obvious candidates are the Millenium Prize Problems on the Yang–Mills existence and mass gap and on Navier–Stokes existence and smoothness. But my understanding is that a proof of Yang-Mills existence and mass gap probably wouldn't be of much *physical* interest to working theoretical (as opposed to mathematical) physicists. Unless the proof had a surprising physical consequence as a corollary or led to new calculational techniques, it probably wouldn't really change the day-to-day practice of most working quantum field theorists. (That is, QFT practitioners are pretty confident that there's *some* mathematical structure which is described by their QFT's, and if that structure turns out not to satisfy the Wightman axioms required by the Millenium Prize problem, that wouldn't be a big deal practically.) Similarly, a proof of Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness (which didn't lead to new calculational techniques) wouldn't necessarily change the study of fluid mechanics in the sense of making novel predictions that could be tested by experimentalists.

Ideally, I'd like an open problem worked on by real mathematicians which would conclusively answer some question with both theoretical and experimental physics importance (at least within some widely-accepted theoretical framework). I know that's a bit vague and subjective, but hopefully not too much.

Comment: There are many sequences/integrals/etc. that have no known closed-form formula. Some of them have direct applications to physics. Would that work as an example of an open problem with relevance to physics?

Comment: Interesting question and I'm curious to see what answers turn up. Does history count? If mathematicians hadn't come up with non-Euclidean geometry and the tensor calculus it's hard to see how Einstein could have formulated GR.

Comment: [Open problems in mathematical physics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275011/open-problems-in-mathematical-physics), [Open problems in PDEs, dynamical systems, mathematical physics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125049/open-problems-in-pdes-dynamical-systems-mathematical-physics).

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: Can I just throw in current work on the Three Body Problem, which in this link seems to refer to non numerical methods, and is based on symmetries , at least in part: http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2013/03/physicists-discover-whopping-13-new-solutions-three-body-problem

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Sure, if there are mathematicians actively working on finding those closed forms and you can provide a physics context in which that sequence/integral arises. But I don't think these kind of questions are considered interesting by the professional math community. For example, my understanding is that [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) together pretty much resolve the question of which antiderivatives can be expressed in closed form.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'm mostly wondering about the present. I'd also be interested to hear about concrete previously open problems in math which where already known to have physics applications before being resolved. Your examples seem to just be general applications of (already understood) advanced math to physics, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tparker: Sure; I was just pointing out a historical example to show that this has happened. It's interesting, I think that Clifford quite soon after Riemann formulated the notion of a manifold declared that motion would be found to be waves in spacetime but it took the genius of Einstein to get real physical clarity on this.

Comment: As Qmechanic said, this appears to be a list-based question which is generally considered off-topic as *too broad* (because any answer is a valid answer).

Comment: @KyleKanos And yet no one's posted any answer...

Comment: @tparker: which is completely irrelevant to the fact that you're asking for a list

Comment: @KyleKanos Why is that irrelevant? The motivation for considering list-based questions off-topic is that they might generate too many answers to be useful. If an (in principle) list-based question has a narrow-enough range of answers that no one in the community can come up with any, then how is it "too broad" to be on topic?

Comment: @tparker not sure why such a high rep member is wasting time with something so blatantly off-topic, but answers **never** matter about the topicality of a question; you close a question, not the answers.

Comment: Perhaps one or more answers can be found here:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motives+in+physics